cv2.matchTemplate function fails in matching
I would like to compare two image and find position of template inside  second image, so first image is this:

This is our template image that should be compared to the following image:

But when I run the code, I got following  result:

How can I improve result?
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
template =cv2.imread("euro.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
template =cv2.resize(template,(99,99))
img =cv2.imread("euro_2024.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img2 = img.copy()
# image =cv2.resize(image,(700,700))
h,w =template.shape[:2]

# All the 6 methods for comparison in a list
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR',
            'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']

for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)

    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

    # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
    if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

    cv2.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)

    plt.show()


Your template is too large containing other stuff in the background of the image that does not match and reduces your match score. Crop it about the ball and make a mask showing only the ball in white and the rest black. Then use the mask in your matchTemplate

so should i resize or?

this cannot be solved by template matching. you've got different views of a 3d object.
